# Pandas module read_csv reads file within Eclipse+pydev while fail if I run standalone

Tags: csv, pandas

I'm currently developing a GUI using Python and Tkinter.
On of the task is to open and read some *.csv files.
I order to perform this task I have written the following code:

```
ReadData=pd.read_csv(ResultFile,skipinitialspace=True).values
```

While I'm running the code within the IDE Eclipse+Pydev everything work fine. But as soon as I run my code form a Dos window, i.e. `python MainGrap.py`, the code bugs stating that the file doesn't exists???????
I first load the path to a file via `self.Inp_Filename=askopenfilename()` then I create a list of the folders by means of the following function:

```
def PathDisintegrator(Inp_File):
    Folders = os.path.split(Inp_File)
    LastFolder = Folders[1]
    RootPath = Folders[0]
    Dirs=[]
    while not(LastFolder==''):
        Dirs.insert(0,LastFolder)
        Folders = os.path.split(RootPath)
        LastFolder = Folders[1]
        RootPath = Folders[0]
    Dirs.insert(0,RootPath[:-1])
    Dirs=Dirs[:-1] 
    return(Dirs)
```

Then I can recreate the full path to file via the following function:

```
def PathAndFile(Folders,File):
    FileOut=''
    for item in Folders:
        FileOut=FileOut+os.sep+item
        #FileOut=FileOut+r"\\"+item
    FileOut=FileOut[1:]+os.sep+File 
    return(FileOut)
```

I have printed out the file path even within the parser of Pandas and it looks fine to me: `D:\Abaqus_Runs\DOWLEX_PET_LAMINATE_PROTO_REFERENCE_SI_Version_2_Revision_2_MDangle0_Rate0_01_MOVING_NODE_out.csv`

Comment: Because your path to your csv is not visible to python when running it outside of eclipse, you should probably provide the full path to the csv file to ensure it works

Comment: You can easily debug this by printing `ResultFile` and also you can print the visible directories by doing `import sys print(sys.path)`

Comment: Your path contains back slashes could you either try constructing raw string so `'r'D:\Abaqus_Runs\DOWLEX_PET_LAMINATE_PROTO_REFERENCE_SI_Version_2_Revision_2_MDangle0_Rate0_01_MOVING_NODE_out.csv'` or convert to forward slashes or escape the back slashes : `D:\\Abaqus_Runs\\DOWLEX_PET_LAMINATE_PROTO_REFERENCE_SI_Version_2_Revision_2_MDangle0_Rate0_01_MOVING_NODE_out.csv`

Comment: I have used os.sep that automatically add  escaped back slash. In fact I have compared the 'ResultFile111=PathAndFile(DirectoriesInpFile,ResultFileCSV[:-1])' with "D:\\Abaqus_Runs\\DOWLEX_PET_LAMINATE_PROTO_REFERENCE_SI_Version_2_Revision_2_MDangle0_Rate0_01_MOVING_NODE_out.csv" and thay are exacly the  same....

Comment: Well then you have another problem, please re-check if that path is valid as from what you've stated it should work fine

Comment: So it is crazy but indeed the two string are identical if test them within Eclipse+Pydev but If test them from terminal they are not O_O.....OMG....I have discovered that running from terminal the constructed path is one charter longer, i.e. 113 instead of 112

Comment: That sounds like your problem, find the errant character and fix the path

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that your python environment in eclipse can see the folder where your csv resides but the terminal one does not.

You can observe what the system paths are by doing:

```
In [331]:

import sys
sys.path
Out[331]:
['',
 'C:\\WinPython-64bit-3.4.2.4\\python-3.4.2.amd64\\python34.zip',
 'C:\\WinPython-64bit-3.4.2.4\\python-3.4.2.amd64\\DLLs',
 'C:\\WinPython-64bit-3.4.2.4\\python-3.4.2.amd64\\lib',
 'C:\\WinPython-64bit-3.4.2.4\\python-3.4.2.amd64',
 'C:\\WinPython-64bit-3.4.2.4\\python-3.4.2.amd64\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\WinPython-64bit-3.4.2.4\\python-3.4.2.amd64\\lib\\site-packages\\win32',
 'C:\\WinPython-64bit-3.4.2.4\\python-3.4.2.amd64\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
 'C:\\WinPython-64bit-3.4.2.4\\python-3.4.2.amd64\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin',
 'C:\\WinPython-64bit-3.4.2.4\\python-3.4.2.amd64\\lib\\site-packages\\IPython\\extensions']
```

So you need to provide a complete path or append the path to where the csv resides to your sys path. Note that backslashes must be escaped e.g. `'c:\\data\\my.csv'` but if you use forward slashes then it works fine: e.g. `'c:/data/my.csv'`

Comment: I have already provided the full path to the *.csv file. In fact I load the full path via 'Inp_Filename=askopenfilename()' and then I store the single directories that I have identified via itertive use of 'Folders = os.path.split(Inp_File)'. Later when I need a file path I build it using os.sep.... That's way i don't understand I'm using absolute path to every file...

Comment: Can you edit your question with your full path and the code that shows how you create the path